# Back button custom image

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, xcode6

I am trying to use a custom image for back button in my iOS app. I see a unexplained line in the back button when I use following code.

```
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), forBarMetrics: .Default)

    var backImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "back-button")!
    var barBackBtnImg: UIImage = backImage.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 0))
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(barBackBtnImg, forState: UIControlState.Normal, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Attached is the screenshot of what it is right now.

[image]

If I remove

```
var barBackBtnImg: UIImage = backImage.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 0))
```

it looks like this:

[image]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is happening because you have told it that it is resizable. Your provided cap insets are causing the OS to grab the right-most pixels and stretch them.

Comment: Please see edited question. I tried removing the resizable code.

Comment: The back button will impose cap insets to attempt to "nicely" stretch your image. If you want your image to be in a specific spot, you can do one of two things: set an empty image for the button and then add the arrow as a `UIImageView` subview of the button and position it how you like; or you can add transparent padding to the edge of the image and allow that to stretch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me!!!

```
var backImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "back-button")!
backImage = backImage.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backImage
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
```